# Confusion with PHP scope while using functions

Tags: php, scope

I have two different .php files, the first one is called `get_data.php` and looks like this:

```
<?php
    ...

    $current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $total_sales = 35;
    $total_revenue = 12;

    $this_month_sales = 3;
    $this_month_revenue = 7;

    $last_month_sales = 2;
    $last_month_revenue = 5;

    ...
?>
```

Now, the second file I'm using is called `index.php`, and up at the top of `index.php` i have the following code, before any of my HTML

```
<?php include_once 'get_data.php'; ?>
```

Now, I can reference the values of `get_data.php` from inside of `index.php` by simply typing in the variable name, this works.

However, I have a `function()` inside of `index.php` that I'm using to check the values and return a percentage as a string

This function looks like this:

```
function compareMonths($checkingRevenue) {
    global $this_month_revenue;
    global $this_month_sales;
    global $last_month_revenue;
    global $last_month_sales;

    ...
}
```

However, this function is returning "0" for all four variables. I have tried not setting them as global as-well. How can I get the values from `get_data.php` to be in the scope of my function inside of index.php?

The solution for this that I had was to just put the function inside of get_data.php, however I want to know how to set the scope correctly so I can do things like this in the future.

This confuses me because the documentation for include_once states

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on > which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will > be available within the called file, from that point forward. However, all functions and > classes defined in the included file have the global scope.

Which means it should be accessible, shouldn't it?

Comment: But they're still variables outside of the function scope so you either have to pass them into the function or declare them as global inside of the function. The first method is preferable because global declarations often get lost in the scaling of larger applications.

Comment: I hate walls-of-code..

Comment: Meaning the correct way to do this would be something like `compareMonths($checkingRevenue, $this_r, $this_s, $last_r, $last_s) { }` ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: @Flosculus - Most people complain when you don't post code.

Comment: I know, but you already know what the problem is, so you could shake it down to include only the problem.

Comment: He may know the problem but if passing the variables as parameters didn't occur to him, he probably can't tell what is relevant and what's not.

Comment: @Flosculus -- I did some cuts, better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming

```
global $this_month_revenue;
global $this_month_sales;
global $last_month_revenue;
global $last_month_sales;
```

are the variables you want to pass to the function when you call it. ex:

```
compareMonths($checkingRevenue, $this_month_revenue, $this_month_sales);

function compareMonths($checkingRevenue, $val1, $val2) {}
```